# Html5 pattern attribute not matching for email(user@gmail.com)

Tags: html, regex, forms, email-validation, html-input

I am new to HTML5...

Here i am having some problem with email pattern attribute...

1)if i am giving the input like user@gmail.com... in email field..

2)it's not accepting value and showing "Pattern not matched"..

Help me to fix this....

Here is the snippet of Html

```
<form name='f1' method="POST" action=""  >     
  <div id="fp">


        <span style="margin-left:-50px">Email:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span><input  class="input" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter mailID" required pattern="^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$" ></span><br>


         <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit">

   </div>
  </form>
```

Any suggestions are acceptable....

Comment: Take a look at http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/ — it contains nice examples of valid e-mail addresses, like `"Abc@def"@example.com` (one of the nice ones).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this should be correct pattern

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}
```

yes you forgot to consider lower case.

you can refer this document for more details

[html5-form-validation-with-regex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29)

Comment: But it is checking up to @ after that one letter then it is not considering overall.. For Example.... If i typed like user@g it's taking it as a email... but actually user@gmail.com is the correct format... how can i do that...

Comment: That was never correct. Doesn't match internationalized TLDs (info@example.xn--xkc2dl3a5ee0h), or longer TLDs (info@example.exchange)

Comment: how about `^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$` for longer domains?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer won't validate marian@iflove.technology
In this case not to miss out all those new domain names emails like http://www.iflove.technology/ you could use:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

Used with input type email it looks like this:

```
<input type="email" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}">
```

Comment: this still allows for an bad email example like 'hello@world'

Answer (score 4):

You need to account for lower cases too. Or make it case insensitive. But in reality you should just use:

```
^.+@.+$
```

And send a confirmation e-mail to the address that they should follow because e-mail addresses are reasonably complicated and you'll end up blocking stuff you don't intend to with a regex and it doesn't stop someone putting in a fake e-mail address anyway.

Comment: This is the only correct regexp in all answers here. The fully-featured regexp to match all possible e-mail addresses is a page long grey rectangle which causes serious headaches — see http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to validate Email correctly simply using HTML5 attribute "pattern". If you do not use a "pattern" someone@ will be processed. which is NOT valid email.

Using pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" will require the format to be someone@email.com

Comment: still doesn't allow for correct email format such as "hello@world.com"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this pattern right now, seems to work just fine:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

Comment: info@dot.swiss disagrees.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `pattern` attribute. The `type="email"` is enough.

Comment: Not true. HTML5 won't catch a bad email like "hello@world"

Comment: @JesseNovotny Full check according to RFCs is very hard to get right and impractical to implement. For usual applications it is much better to let libraries and other available tools to do the check for you, even if it is not perfect. To decide that "hello@world" is invalid you need to check that "world" is FQDN. That is too complex job for a text input. For example "spam@ai" is a valid e-mail address.

Answer (score -1):

My solution to override html5 validation type='email'. I run this code after DOM loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=email]').attr('pattern', "^([\\w]+[\\.]{0,1})+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w]{2,4}$").attr('type', 'text').attr('title', 'Please enter an email address')
})
```

Comment: info@dot.swiss disagrees.

Comment: hello@world disagrees